# compare if with hebrew letter

Tags: php, hebrew

I write code that work only with english letters. when I ctry to do it with hebrew letter I get error.

the code:

```
<?php
$idan="emr";
$firstletter = mb_substr($idan, 0, 1, 'UTF-8');
if ($firstletter=='e') 
echo "tov";
else echo "lo tove";
?>
```

work good.
but the code:

```
<?php
$idan="אבהבה";
$firstletter = mb_substr($idan, 0, 1, 'UTF-8');
if ($firstletter=='א') 
echo "tov";
else echo "lo tove";
?>
```

not work, How I can to fix it?

Comment: Can you post the error you receive?

Comment: This is a Unicode rather than Hebrew problem.

Comment: I'm not get Error, I get "lo tove" but it need be "tov"

Answer (score 3):

You do realize that `mb_substr` works from left to right? (is Hebrew written from right to left?) You are therefore reading the first character which is `ה` not `א`. To get the first letter from the right (the last one), use `-1` as a starting index:

```
$firstletter = mb_substr($idan, -1, 1, 'UTF-8');
```

You can also use `mb_internal_encoding("UTF-8");` to set the encoding for every call, instead of propagating it (if you're making many calls to `mb_` functions)

**Edit:** Following your comments, here's a quick example of a script that handles letters depending on the language:

```
$desiredLetter = 'e';
$startIndex = 0;

// some condition to figure out the language
if(mb_detect_encoding($idan, 'ASCII', true) == FALSE)
{
    $desiredLetter = 'א';
    $startIndex = -1;
}

$firstletter = mb_substr($idan, $startIndex, 1, 'UTF-8');
if ($firstletter == $desiredLetter) 
    echo "tov";
else 
    echo "lo tove";
```

Comment: and if I need to compare in the script also with english word?

Comment: `PHP` strings always work from left to right, so `0` will be the left-most character and `-1` the right-most. You will need to know which letter you're looking for to use the right index (English / Hebrew)

Comment: I need both... Sometimes the variable Hebrew and sometimes in English

Comment: Hebrew text is always displayed RTL. Despite being displayed at the right end of the string, `א` is the first character.

Answer (score 1):

Your code worked correctly (*e.g.* printed `tov`) when I saved it to a PHP file and ran it. If you are seeing different results, you may want to check your text editor settings and ensure that you're saving the file as UTF-8.

Comment: +1, should have ran the code, I assumed a left/right issue since I've never dealt with that kind of language before